# How to color the items in a listbox in C# windows application

Tags: c#

How to color the string in a List box in C# Windows Application?

Like:

If the string is "green"---> color should be green

red-->red

Comment: Which technology ? WPF, Windows Forms ?

Comment: that doesn't answer our question, WPF and Windows forms can both produce Windows Applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx) if you want to paint each item individually, which is what i think you're trying to do.

Comment: +1: Well that's my answer made useless. I do wish folks would ask for what they want, and not ask for things they don't want.